# How do I create a radial blur in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, blur

I don't remember how to do it I am on a layer mask but I forget what to do after that I remember you can do it but that is about it

Answer (score 2):

Uhm... do you Mean Filter > Blur > Radial Blur

Comment: Yes lol Because I remember things.